# MacOS source .bash_profile cause repeat message print

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I have a problem when I use `source .bash_profile` in the terminal. It print many same messages like this:

```
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
```

And when I reopen the terminal, the same repeat messages print again:

`Last login: Mon Apr 17 10:11:57 on ttys000
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
-bash: /Users/wuyiqing: is a directory
MacBook-Pro:~ wuyiqing$`

And my .bash_profile is like this:

`export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/keso/Library/Tomcat/bin 
~
~
~`

I have try to fix this but failed. How could I make the repeat message disappear?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what's in your `.bash_profile`...

Comment: I hava added the .bash_file content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `~` lines in your .bash_profile will cause that error message. `~` is shell shorthand for the path to your home folder, so those lines expand to `/Users/wuyiqing`. Since that's the first thing on the line, it's treated as a command to execute, but it's not a command, it's a directory, so you get the message "/Users/wuyiqing: is a directory".

One thing confuses me: according to what you posted, .bash_profile contains three `~` lines, but you're seeing that as an error message sixteen times. Did you post the full .bash_profile? Anyway, the solution is simple: remove those lines.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works well. And the .bash_profile content I sent was't full, because I thought the repeat ~ was unimportant. Now I think that I have made a mistake.